# Computer reboots seconds after shutdown

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, shutdown

My computer restarts itself just a few seconds after shutting down. This is what I have tried thus far. The motherboard of the computer is an ASUS H97M-E

1. Booting into a different OS. I tried both Windows 7 and Ubuntu and got the same result.
2. Resetting the CMOS battery.
3. Unplugging the power button from the computer case and starting the computer by having a screwdriver touching the power prongs (I'm not sure what other word to use).
4. Made sure Native Power Management is disabled in the BIOS.

The only way to make it fully shut down is to press and hold the power button for long enough until after it would have started up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up working for me was replacing the small 3V battery in the motherboard. NOTE: Both batteries had the required voltage so don't be fooled if your battery reads correctly.